# jQuery : dynamically created div ID can't be selected?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

```
$('#content').droppable({
    drop:function(event , ui){  
        $('<div>').appendTo('#content');
        $('#content div').load('div.html');
                             }
                        });
```

**Below code doesn't select the divContainer ID**

```
$('#divContainer').click(function(){
    $('#divContainer').hide(); 
});
```

This is my html page DIV.html

```
<div id="divContainer">
    SampleDIV  
 </div>
```

*The DIv gets added to my page but i can't select the div using it's ID !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $('#divContainer').click code needs to go inside the done section once the data is loaded in

```
$('#result').load('div.html', function() {
    $('#divContainer').click(function(){
        $('#divContainer').hide(); 
    });
});
```

or use on() as Explosion Pills said

Answer (score 1):

Try using event delegation.

```
$("#content").on('click', '#divContainer', function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: cool. It works. can you please explain me this ? thanks

Comment: `$('#divContainer').click(function(){` calls the `.click` method on all existing `#divContainer` elements.  If no `#divContainer` elements exist yet, this call doesn't actually do anything because there is nothing to bind to.  Event delegation is designed for this purpose: so you can bind to an element that already exists but the event is only triggered during a match of the second argument during the capture phase.